# parse serial data while receiving in arduino

Tags: string, arduino

I am receiving telemetry data as CSV data like below in an arduino pro mini trough serial:

> 1,123,3242,34234,3424,124312;

with a ; at the end to show end of each packet.
i want to parse it into an array of double(or int. it doesn't matter)
i don't want to make my code heavy with looping the string after receiving.
so is there a way to separate it when it is is being received ?
i wanted to use readStringUntil(',');   but there will be a problem with the ; at the end. and i should have that ; at the end because there maybe be some noise and corrupted packets received so i need to determine when the packet is ended.
This is how i managed to just receive string without separation:

```
 while (trans.available()>0) {
String temp = trans.readStringUntil(';');
lastTelemetry = temp;
 Serial.print(lastTelemetry);
}
```

trans is my softwareSerial.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way: Read the string one character at a time and check for your different termination characters yourself. Use an array index, a packet index and a temporary string you fill each char in, and when you reach `,` or `;`, parse it into a number, store it and increase the array index, and when you reach `;`, additionally increase the packet index and use a new array.

Comment: Thanks  yes it makes sense but i was looking for a more easier and less dirty way:)